# how can I get a sequence to increment by one in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

At the moment I have a sequence in the format:

```
      CREATE SEQUENCE calc_emp_id
      MINVALUE 1001 MAXVALUE 10000
      START WITH 1006 INCREMENT BY 1 ORDER NOCACHE;
```

The table I'm inserting into already has six inserts and I'm trying to get the next insert to have a primary key of 1007. It increments by 2 for the first insert and then by 3 for subsequent ones. I am inserting using calc_emp_id.NEXTVAL in an insert statement.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the code where you're using the sequence? It's hard to say what's the cause without the context.

Comment: selct calc_emp_id.currval from dual;

Comment: Read this [AskTom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:530735152441) about why a sequence is never "gap free"

Comment: Thanks all, I think the link A.B.Cade has posted explains it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use CURRVAL after nextval

Comment: Good guess on what he is doing wrong. Everytime you call NEXTVAL, you increment the sequence, use CURRVAL if you just want the current sequence instead of incrementing it.

Comment: CURRVAL returns the current sequence value in *your session*.  If we haven't previously issued a NEXTVAL a call to CURRVAL will hurl.